# Decryption at client side using java

Tags: java, encryption, gwt, aes

I encypted the session Id at server side but when I am trying to decrypt the session id at client side some error is coming. please can anyone help resolving the error.

```
public static String decrypt(String sessionId)
{
    try
    {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5PADDING");
        final SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
        final String decryptedSessionId = new String(cipher.doFinal(Base64.decodeBase64(sessionId)));
        return decryptedSessionId;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
    return null;
}
```

The error that is coming is :
Class 'javax.crypto.Cipher' is not present in JRE Emulation Library so it cannot be used in client code of "some" GWT module.

This inspection reports usages in client code of JDK classes which is not present in JRE Emulation Library.

The method for encryption that I used is :

```
    public static String encrypt(String sessionId)
{
    try
    {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
        final SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
        final String encryptedSessionId = Base64.encodeBase64String(cipher.doFinal(sessionId.getBytes()));
        return encryptedSessionId;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;

}
```

I am new to this stuff please help me resolving the errors

Comment: It's a suggestion (not answer). As you using GWT move code to server side (RPC). that way there will be no need  for emulation. Maybe you can use JDK on client side.

Comment: **Never use [ECB mode](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/14487/13022)**. It's deterministic and therefore not semantically secure. You should at the very least use a randomized mode like [CBC](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/22260/13022) or [CTR](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/2378/13022). It is better to authenticate your ciphertexts so that attacks like a [padding oracle attack](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/18185/13022) are not possible. This can be done with authenticated modes like GCM or EAX, or with an [encrypt-then-MAC](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/202/13022) scheme.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you cannot use java standard encryption library in GWT coding on client side. It's not supported.

Use [gwt-crypto](https://code.google.com/archive/p/gwt-crypto/wikis/Usage.wiki) to encrypt/decrypt the necessary stuff.

AES is not be supported on client side for GWT in GWT-crypto, but you can use TripleDES. TripleDES is also very much secure implementation.

Comment: The link you provided is using DES approach, I already have the DES implementation apporach but I need to implement using AES.

Comment: I think there isn't any library to support AES decryption at client side in Java so I need to use JSNI for implementing the same. am I correct?

Comment: AES might not be supported on client side for GWT, but you can use TripleDES. TripleDES is also very much secure implementation.