# AES decryption at Client side

Tags: java, gwt, cryptography, aes

I have encrypted the session id at server side using AES but not able to decrypt the encrypted session id at client side, As there isn't any AES library defined for GWT to support AES decryption in java. 
The code snippet for AES encryption at server side is :

```
    public static String encrypt(String sessionId)
{
    try
    {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        String key = "Abcdefghijklmnop";

        final SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), "AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
        final String encryptedSessionId = Base64.encodeBase64String(cipher.doFinal(sessionId.getBytes()));
        return encryptedSessionId;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;

}
```

For decryption I am trying with the code provided in this link :
http://reassess.blogspot.in/2009/07/gwt-and-aes-decryption.html

But this isnt working. Please provide any solution if anyone has.

I have tried encryption and decryption in DES but I need to use AES.

Comment: What is the purpose of encrypting the session id?

Comment: This snippet you've shown produces undecryptable ciphertexts because the IV is not saved. The IV is not secret, so you can send it along with the ciphertext. Usually, it is simply prepended to the ciphertext and sliced off before decryption.

Comment: If you're using only symmetric encryption you need the exact same key at the server and the client. If you send the encryption key from the server to the client or the other way around you need to encrypt your symmetric encryption key. The easiest way to do this would be to use TLS. If you use TLS, then the data as well as key are encrypted, so you don't need to encrypt it yourself. This doesn't provide any security, just a little bit of obfuscation. You should read: https://www.nccgroup.trust/us/about-us/newsroom-and-events/blog/2011/august/javascript-cryptography-considered-harmful/

Comment: Okay I will try with IV, But the problem is that at client side the error that is coming is  : Cannot read property 'AES' of undefinedcom.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (TypeError) : Cannot read property 'AES' of undefined.

Answer (score 0):

AES is not be supported on client side for GWT, but you can use TripleDES. TripleDES is also very much secure implementation.

Here it's another similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45737528/decryption-at-client-side-using-java/45737631#45737631)

Here are list of known issues for GWT-crypto.

https://code.google.com/archive/p/gwt-crypto/issues

See #1  issue- AES Encrypted content cant' be decrypted by Java AES Decryptor & Vice Versa

Comment: In question I mentoned that I already have implemented the DES  approach. Ii need to implement using AES due to requirement.